# Need help with getting List Item counts

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, xslt, caml

I have a custom list created that tracks project status by stages. I need to present the same in a chart format. Below is the list information.

Columns
*Project Name
*Development(Phase1)
*Testing(Phase2)
*Deployed(Phase3)

Status for each of the phase is NA, WIP, Completed.

Output required is Stage wise total counts of Status. Below is view on status for 5 projects.

Development(Phase1) - WIP(1) - NA(2) - Completed(2)
Testing(Phase2) - WIP(1) - NA(3) - Completed(1)
Deployed(Phase3) - WIP(0) - NA(4) - Completed(1)

Can this be done using CAML or DVWP XSL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with XSL and CAML.  I have done similar to create a Risk Matrix which is detailed on my [blog](http://paylord.wordpress.com).  You will have to adjust the concept to meet your own requirements but it should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Depending on what you want to achieve you could also create a basic bar chart in the XSL sizing SPAN objects based on the numbers returned.